# SQL Server -- Efficient String Contains Over Very Large Tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table that currently contains 10 million records.

One of the columns is `SourceText` of type `nvarchar(4000)`.

I need a *very* efficient way to search the SourceText to see if it contains another string.

I have extreme flexibility will the table structures--I can modify the insert procedure and use other, better indexed tables to track things.  One thought was to  tokenize the SourceText by word and store the words in an indexed table, then use a mapping table to map to the main table.  The problem is that the `SourceText` column can be any language, and there are always rules re:parantheses, etc.  For example, in english if I tokenize using ' ' as the delimiter, I will still get things like `(Where` instead of `Where`, which is problematic.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered Full Text Search ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Comment: That looks interesting; I will give it a shot--it should be interesting to see if it is fast enough...

Answer (score 0):

It would be a quite interesting and challenging project (and I think it's possible) to implement a fast full text search *without* the optional and very powerful [full text search component of SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) ;-)